# Chosen drop down previous options not hide in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using chosen drop down fields and its working fine in desktop but in mobile previous drop down not hide so it seems all the drop down fields are open in mobile.

URL: https://mtest.hotcoursesabroad.com/demo-cont/hcindia/chk/ddchosen.html

help me if any one face same.

[image: screenshot reference]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chosen:hiding_dropdown` event does not trigger on a `blur` event. You'll have to trigger a `chosen:close` event inside `chosen:showing_dropdown` for each select excluding the one that triggers the event. Try the following code:

```js
function chosen() {
  $(".chosen-select").chosen({
    disable_search_threshold: 100,
    inherit_select_classes: true,
    width: '100%'
  }).on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function (evt, params) {

    // Trigger a chosen:close event to all other chosen elements
    $(this).parent().parent().siblings().find('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:close');

    $.js('custom-scroll').find(".chosen-results").niceScroll({
      cursorcolor:"#d1d1d1",
      cursorwidth:"10px",
      background:"#fff",
      cursorborder:"0px solid #eeeeee",
      cursorborderradius:0,
      cursoropacitymin:1,
    });
  });
}
```

Try my fix [here](https://zikro.gr/dbg/so/60695699/).